# I have converted The Red Book 9ed ex. 3.7 from old functions to 4.5 functions, but it's not displaying anything

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

For practice purpose, I have converted OpenGL Red Book 9ed ex. 3.7 from "old" functions to 4.5 functions. I have done it before, and it has worked on my system, but this time, it's not displaying anything, just the `glClearBufferfv()` color. I tried to follow the example to a tee, and I didn't omit anything. I just converted `glBufferData()` to `glNamedBufferStorage()`. And a a few other things. [Here's](http://prntscr.com/matz3o) the original code [as](http://prntscr.com/matzb0) it appears in the book. But let me copy-paste my own code and shaders:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <KHR/khrplatform.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <SOIL2/SOIL2.h>

#include <Shader.h>
#include <Camera.h>


enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs, ID3 };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer1, ArrayBuffer2, EBOBuffer, NumBuffers
};
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0, cPosition = 1 };

GLuint  VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint  Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint NumVertices = 6;

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;



void init()
{
    GLfloat cube_positions[] = {

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f

    };

    GLfloat cube_colors[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f

    };

    GLushort cube_indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5,        
    0xFFFF,                         
    2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7
    };

    glCreateVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glCreateBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[ArrayBuffer1], sizeof(cube_positions), cube_positions, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[ArrayBuffer2], sizeof(cube_colors), cube_colors, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[EBOBuffer], sizeof(cube_indices), cube_indices, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    Shader myShader("TirangleVert.glsl", "TriangleFrag.glsl");

    myShader.Use();

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer2]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[EBOBuffer]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(cPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) sizeof(cube_positions));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(cPosition);





}

void display()
{
    GLfloat black[] = { 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.6f };

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[EBOBuffer]);
    glLineWidth(20);
    glPointSize(20);
    glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
    glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xFFFF);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 17, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
    //  (const GLvoid *)(9 * sizeof(GLushort)));


}

void dealloc()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glDeleteBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
}

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);



    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    init();

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------       
        display();

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    dealloc();

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

**TirangleVert.glsl**:

```
#version 450 core


layout (location = 0) in vec4 cube_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 colors; 

out vec4 myColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = cube_pos;

    myColor = colors;



}
```

**TriangleFrag.glsl**:

```
#version 450 core


layout (location = 0) in vec4 myColor;

out vec4 color;


void main()
{
    color = myColor;
}
```

PS: I realize that there's a typo in the name of the vertex shader, but it's all accounted for. Also, there's no problem with Shader.h, as I have used it before with no issues.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of the [`glNamedBufferStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferStorage.xhtml) is the bitfield, which specifies the intended usage of the buffer's data store, rather than `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`or `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. This will cause a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error:

```cpp
GLbitfield flags = GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT;
glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[ArrayBuffer1], sizeof(cube_positions), cube_positions, flags);
glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[ArrayBuffer2], sizeof(cube_colors), cube_colors, flags);
glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[EBOBuffer], sizeof(cube_indices), cube_indices, flags);
```

[`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) specifies a vertex array which is refers to the array buffer which is currently bound.
The proper buffer has to be bound by [`glBindBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml) before `glVertexAttribPointer` is called. Note, there is only 1 buffer which can be currently bound.
If a buffer is bound, then the last parameter (*pointer*) is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store. In your case this parameter has to be 0. Note, in a core profile context you have to use an array buffer, a directly addressed memory is not valid.

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[EBOBuffer]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer2]);
glVertexAttribPointer(cPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(cPosition);
```